# Как передать список во фрагмент с использованием Retrofit и RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview, retrofit

Я пытаюсь получить список с использованием `Retrofit` и `RecyclerView` во фрагмент. В классе `RestClient` не получается передать именно список, а не отдельную какую-то строку в опредеоенной позиции. И так же в классе фрагмента не понимаю, куда извлечь полученные данные. По идее в список, но как?

мой класс RestClient:

```
public class RestClient implements Callback <Source> {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://frt.org/v2/";

    private ApiInterface apiInterface;
    private MainActivity mainActivity;
    public RestClient(MainActivity mainActivity) {
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }

    public void start() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<Source> news = apiInterface.getNews();
        news.enqueue(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Source> call, Response<Source> response) {
        Source source = response.body();
        String sourceName = source.getName();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("sourceName", sourceName);
        FragmentManager fm = mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        NameFragment fragmentCurrent = new NameFragment();
        fragmentCurrent.setArguments(bundle);
        ft.add(R.id.fragment, fragmentCurrent);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Source> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.d("error", "can't parse data: ", t);
    }
}
```

мой класс фрагмент:

```
public class NameFragment extends Fragment {
    private List<Source> sources = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    //private MainActivity mainActivity;

        @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.name_fragment, container, false);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new NewsAdapter(getActivity(),sources));

        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (bundle!=null) {
            String sourcNam = bundle.getString("sourceName");
           ???
        }
                return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас не в ту сторону граф зависимостей "построен".
RestClient ничего не должен знать ни об activity, ни о каких-либо фрагментах.

В activity вставьте фрагмент, в фрагменте обратитесь к RestClient'у за данными, и в onResponse отстройте список. Псевдокод:

```
MainActivity.onCreate {
  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(NameFragment.newInstance()).commit();
}

// https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter
NewsAdapter extends androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListDataper<News, NewsHolder>{
     ...
}

NameFragment.onViewCreated {
  recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
  restClient.getNews(adapter::submitList);
}

interface ResponseCallback {
  void done(List<Source> response);
}

restClient.getNews(ResponseCallback cb){
        Call<List<Source>> news = apiInterface.getAllNews();
        news.enqueue(new Callback <List<Source>>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Source>> call, Response<List<Source>> response) {
                cb.done(response.body());
            }
            ...
        );
}
```

ЗЫ Это все начало пути.

Comment: спасибо за совет!буду пробовать